# Can you gulp clean all files in a directory except for a single file?

Tags: node.js, gulp

Is there a way to use gulp-clean such that instead of passing in the files or directories I want to delete, to delete everything that does not match a specific file name in the directory?

For example, If I have 3 files in directory "dir":

```
dir/a.js
dir/b.js
dir/c.js
```

Sample Pseudocode of what I want to do, (delete everything in /dir/ thats not a.js:

```
gulp.src('!./dir/a.js').pipe(clean());
```

Answer (score 42):

This should work:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');

gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
    del(['dir/**/*', '!dir/a.js'], cb);
});
```

If the excluded file is in a sub directory you need to exclude that dir from deletion. For example:

`del(['dir/**/*', '!dir/subdir', '!dir/subdir/a.js'], cb);`

or:

`del(['dir/**/*', '!dir/subdir{,/a.js}'], cb);`

Comment: If a file is under a nested folder, we must specifically exclude each folder. Like  del(['build/app/**/*','!build/app/X', '!build/app/X/Y', '!build/app/X/Y/*.pdf']);

Answer (score 2):

[gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter) can be used to filter files from a gulp stream:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var filter = require('gulp-filter');

gulp.src('**/*.js')
    .pipe(filter(['*', '!dir/a.js']))
    .pipe(clean());
```